# Temporarily prevent/allow exporting to specific folders

Tags: export, files-and-directories, system

Is it possible to temporarily

Q1) prevent exporting to specific folders ?
Q2) allow exporting to only specific folders ?

Whenever mathematica is about to process `Export` command, *make* mathematica always consider Q1) or Q2).

I think we can use `SetOptions`(still have a long way to go)

The method must be mathematica-level, not OS-level like protecting folder, read-only, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe there is a system option for this. One method you could use would be to write your own wrapper function like:

```
myExport[args__] := If[allowedDirectoryQ[args],
    Export[args], 
    issueMessageAndReturnFailure[args]
]
```

where you would need to provide definitions for `allowedDirectoryQ` and `issueMessageAndReturnFailure`.

Comment: Thank you, I think I made it a little complicated thought.